how to add attention for lstm?
Here is the code of my model:
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_layers,output_size,batch_size,seq_length) -> None:
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.input_size=input_size
        self.hidden_size=hidden_size
        self.num_layers=num_layers
        self.output_size=output_size
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.seq_length=seq_length
        self.num_directions=1 
        self.liner1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.liner2 = nn.Linear(num_layers*hidden_size, output_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
 
        self.lstm=nn.LSTM(input_size=hidden_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,num_layers=num_layers,batch_first=True,dropout=0.2) # LSTM
 
    def forward(self,x):
        batchsize = x.shape[0]
        x = self.liner1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
 
        h_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to('cuda')
        c_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to('cuda')
 
        output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0)) 
 
        output = h_n.permute(1,0,2).reshape(batchsize, -1) # 64,10,32  -> 64,32*2
        pred = self.dropout(output)
        pred = self.liner2(pred)     
        pred = pred[:, -1]     # (batch_size,)
        return pred         

and here is the config:
    seq_length = 10  
    input_size = 3  
    num_layers = 2 
    hidden_size = 128 
    batch_size = 64
    n_iters = 10000 
    lr = 0.0001
    output_size = 1
    split_ratio = 0.9
    path = 'data/raw_sales.csv'
    moudle = Net(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, batch_size, seq_length)
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(moudle.parameters(), lr=lr)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()

one result of the model without attention,black is prediction while other color is real:
enter image description here
and the reason why i want to add the attention is because the datasets is about house price sales,the it has five features,includes time,propertyType,postcode,price,bedrooms.And i think the bedrooms number(for example,1 bedrooms,2 bedrooms)lead the key point in price difference.
So the question is how to add an attention on my model?
expecting:
the model can detect the difference of price mainly on bedrooms number.
